# append <tr> and <th colspan='12'> in order to show data group wise and each group starts with 1 number

Tags: html, jquery

I am confuse how to render data table properly.
my html code is

```
<table id="EmployeeGrid" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="6"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Employee Info</th>
                            <th colspan="5"><i class="fas fa-file"></i> Contract Info</th>
                            
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <th>IR No.</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Job Title</th>
                            <th>NIC</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Project</th>

                            <th>DOJ</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>St. Date</th>
                            <th>End Date</th>
                            <th>Type</th>

                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr><th colspan="12"></th></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

In html pre define header.  equivalent to  which is rendering by jQuery.

My jQuery code is

```
var DataGrid = $('#EmployeeGrid');
        var url = "{{url('employees/search')}}";
        var dataTable = DataGrid.DataTable({
            dom: "Tlfrtip",
            aaSorting: [], //disabled initial sorting
            ajax: url,
            paging: true,
            searching: false,
            info: true,
            autoWidth: false,
            responsive: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ordering: true,
            lengthMenu: [[10,25, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000], [10,25, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000]],
            pageLength: 10,
            LengthChange: false,
            "scrollX": true,


            /*"columnDefs": [
             {"width": "10%", "targets": 4, "class":'word-wrap'},
             ],*/

            columns: [
                //Table Column Header Collection

                {data: "irp_number"},
                {
                    data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                    var url_edit = "{{url('employees/edit_view')}}";

                    return '<a href="'+url_edit+'/'+data.employee_id+'" data-id="'+data.employee_id+'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit & View Employee">'+data.employee_name+'</a>'

                }
                },
                {data: "empDesignation"},
                {data: "cnic"},
                {data: "empDutyStation"},
                {data: "empGender"},

                {data: "empIRJoiningDate"},
                {data: "empStatus"},
                {data: "empIRJoiningDate"},
                {data: "empIRJoiningDate"},
                {data: "employment_type"}


            ],

        });
```

this works perfect.

**My Question is how to append new Dept : data.depName
as i want to group by it and strat series from 1,2,3...n. next group 1,2,3...n**
like this as shown in figure:
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html

Comment: Col span should be 11, only 11 TH.

Comment: its a example, 11 or 12, is not a question.

Comment: I solve it by my self.